# Why doesn't an event handler inside a for loop work for all iterations?

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

Working on an Etch-A-Sketch project using Vanilla JS. I ran into a problem with my project where I have a for loop which creates a 16 * 16 grid -

```
//makes a 16 x 16 grid - default grid
for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    const div =  document.createElement('div');
    div.style.cssText = 'border: 1px solid black; flex: 1';
    container.appendChild(div);
    // div.addEventListener('mouseover', changeBackground);
    for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++){
        div2 = document.createElement('div');
        div2.classList.add('square');
        div.style.display = 'flex';
        div.appendChild(div2);  

        div2.addEventListener('mouseover', changeBackground);
    }
}
```

[image: Grid created by the for loop]

Inside the inner for loop I have set up an event listener which has a callback called `changeBackground()` - which will randomly change colour when the cursor hovers over the grid - what I was hoping for was to have any square on the grid change colour when the cursor goes over it. However from the image above, only the very last square on the grid changes colour when I hover over the grid freely, whereas any other square on the grid stays white and non-responsive. 
So my question is: Why is the last grid square in the bottom right the only one to change color whereas every other square remains blank?

```
function changeBackground(){
    let randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

    if(randomColor === '1'){
        div2.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        console.log('red');
    } else if(randomColor === '2'){
        div2.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        console.log('blue');
    } else if(randomColor === '3'){
        div2.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        console.log('yellow');
    } else if(randomColor === '4'){
        div2.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
        console.log('orange');
    } else{
        div2.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        console.log('green');
    }
}
```

Comment: `div2` is global - at the end of the loop it's referencing the last element you created

Comment: In your `changeBackground` function you reference `div2` but I do not see it defined in there, it is in the grid function. `div2` contains the last square after it creates the grid which is why it only works on the last square. You want to reference the current div that triggered the event inside the `changeBackground` function, not `div2`

Comment: Ok so I've declared ```const div2 = document.createElement('div');``` inside the inner for loop however that hasn't changed much

Comment: My apologies Chris having a hard time trying to understand - what do you mean by referencing the current div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is get that element reference in your `changeBackground` function

```
function changeBackground(e){
    var div = e.target; // the current div you want to change

    // do your stuff

    div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

I put together a quick example do demonstrate the element references. It gets passed to your `mouseover` function automatically (I used `button` but it works for any element) and I called it `e`. Then you need to pull out the current element using `e.target`.

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('mouseover', whichButton);
}

function whichButton(e) {
  var btn = e.target; // <- This is your current element (in your case, div2)
  console.log(btn);
  
  var span = document.getElementById('spanMO');
  span.textContent = btn.textContent;
}
```

```html
<button>First</button><br/>
<button>Second</button><br/>
<button>Third</button><br/>

<p>
Mouseover: <span id="spanMO"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank  you so much I got it to work - I was just having an issue with my js file for some reason when i save the code and go to see the changes nothing has updated in the chrome tools .> Sources panel - So I manually changed the code and tested it.